# Poco - failure to openApplication log causes subsystem shutdown failure

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I'm using Poco 1.6.0 and the `Util::ServerApplication` structure.

At the start of `int main(const ArgVec& args)` in my main class, I redirect all the logging to a file:

```
Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::FileChannel> chanFile = new Poco::FileChannel;
chanFile->setProperty("path", "C:\\doesnotexist\\file.log");
Poco::Util::Application::instance().logger().setChannel(chanFile);
```

If the log file cannot be opened, this causes an exception to be thrown, which I catch, and return an error code from `main()`. The `Application::run()` code in Poco's `Application.cpp` then calls `Application::uninitialize()`.

The implementation of `Application::uninitialize()`iterates through each SubSystem executing that subsystem's `uninitialize()`.

But one of those is `LogFile::uninitialize()`, which causes the following message to be logged: `Uninitializing subsystem: Logging Subsystem`.

When it attempts to log that message, an exception is thrown since the log file could not be opened (for the same reason as before).   That exception is caught somewhere in Poco's code and it attempts to log an error, which causes an exception, and that one finally terminates the program.

How should I deal with this issue? E.g. is it possible to tell the logging subsystem to not throw any exceptions?

There seems to be a greater issue too; if any subsystem `uninitialize()` throws, this will cause execution to leave the subsystem shutdown loop in `Application.cpp` , so other subsystems will not have a chance to shut down either.

Comment: Currently working around it by logging a start line, seeing if `FileException` is thrown and then calling `setChannel` with a console channel so that `chanFile` is no longer attached,  but that feels hacky and also doesn't address the potential subsystem shutdown problem

Answer (score 3):

You should make sure that the path exist before setting up the file channel, e.g.:

```
if (Poco::File("C:\\doesnotexist").exists())
{
  Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::FileChannel> chanFile = new Poco::FileChannel;
  chanFile->setProperty("path", "C:\\doesnotexist\\file.log");
  Poco::Util::Application::instance().logger().setChannel(chanFile);
}
```

`Application::unitialize()` will loop through subsystems and log iterations as **debug** messages - the idea is to catch problems before release.

UPDATE: as pointed in the comments, the directory may exist at the time of the check but may not exist (or not be accessible) afterwards, when logging actually happens. There is nothing in Poco that shields user from that; so, you will have to make sure the directory exists and is accessible throughout the lifetime of the FileChannel using it. I have not found this to be an obstacle in practice. I did find the initial non-existence of a directory to be an annoying problem and there is a [proposal for addition](http://pocoproject.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=6424&p=11754) of such (optional/configurable) feature but it has not been scheduled yet for inclusion in upcoming releases.

Comment: That can lead to a [time of check to time of use bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use). If that path is removed in between the `exists()` check and the actual attempt to log, then the issue still exists. This same type of bug is the reason [the Linux man pages say to never use `mktemp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mktemp.3.html#BUGS).

Comment: Poco Logger expects the directory to be there when creating log files. To be 100% certain, user can take the necessary steps (ownership, permissions, locking etc). If you think that should be ensured by the framework, send a pull request and we'll look into it.

Comment: I haven't got the time or interest to submit a pull request. Rather, I'm remarking that this answer doesn't truly solve the OP's question/issue. It might be "good enough" for some people, but I think it's worth pointing out this doesn't 100% fix the issue.

Comment: OP asked how he should deal with this issue; given the current state of the affairs, the answer is accurate. He can improve the reliability by taking ownership, locking etc. For anything beyond that, change in the framework is needed.